# Consuming SOAP Web Services in Drupal from C# client

Tags: c#, web-services, drupal, soap, client

I want to make a client in C# in order to create Blog posts in Drupal, so the situation is the following. In Drupal i have Services module and soap_server both enabled and when i consume the wsdl file from http://example.com/services/soap?wsdl is recognizes it properly but i don't know what to do next... I'm stuck. The lack of documentation is a big disappointment for me. Does any one try this before? Any advise will be welcome ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you chose this design for a specific reason that you did not illustrate in your question, but - just in case this is not the case - let me point out how you could leverage the built-in functionalities of Drupal and known API's to achieve what you want in less steps.

1. **Use the [Blog API](http://drupal.org/node/295)** module (shipped with Drupal Core) to expose widely known and well documented API's to the outside world, via the built-in XML-RPC interface.
2. Blog API exposes various blog-oriented API's, which are **documented** [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/blogger/), [here](http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi) and [here](http://www.sixapart.com/developers/xmlrpc/blogger_api/).
3. Use **code available online** to implement the webservice consumer. I know nothing about C#, but from a quick google search, it seems such code is not difficult at all to be found. For example, [here's some code from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905670.aspx) for metaweblog API's.

If for some reason you need or want to implement your own API with SOAP, then **you should specify what your difficulties are**. I assume you already created the SOAP services by following the [documentation](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/services) available online, and in particular [this comment](http://drupal.org/node/113699#comment-2306856) and [this series of screencasts](http://drupal.org/node/144141).

If this is the case, **what is the difficult on the C# side?** As stated before, I do not develop in C#, but - at least by googling it - it does seem like there is [plenty](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Articles/ArticleListing.aspx?SectionID=1&SubSectionID=133) of documentation and sample code available for this.

Comment: I don't want to use the Blog API, instead i want to create my own module in order to create blog posts to Drupal and i want to use SOAP and not XMLRPC which is the dominant in Bloggin Clients.

Comment: Fair enough. You should still tell us what's your difficult though, otherwise it won't be possible to help.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i will reinvent the wheel ... [NuSoap](http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapintro.htm) library is much more simple to use. After extensive survey i have successfully accomplish to consume PHP web services based on NuSoap through C# client. I will make a custom module for drupal that will use NuSoap in order to call it from my C# client.

Comment: If it works for you... go for it! :) I had better luck with the built-in SOAP capability of PHP 5, but nosoap is certainly a valid tool! :)